# How do you use a collection as an argument for a function? (Can't see why my code returns value error)

Tags: vba, excel, collections

I'm having difficulty getting a function with a collection as its argument to do anything.

I have a function that outputs a collection

```
function ext(P as string) as collection
dim serv as new collection
serv.add P, "1"
set ext = serv
end function
```

ive tried to make a second function that takes collections and spits out their first item but it doesn't work

```
function first (C as collection) as string
first = C(1)
end function
```

so when I call

```
first(ext("Apple"))
```

I should get "Apple"
but I get a value error.

does anyone know why?

Comment: This code works fine for me -- `First` returns a string, so make sure there's somewhere for that string to go. E.g. `MsgBox first(ext("Apple"))`

Comment: @CallumDA does it have something to do with me typing it into an excel cell?

=first(ext("Apple"))

?

Answer (score 0):

> does it have something to do with me typing it into an excel cell?

Yes, it has everything to do with that. You can't pass a `Collection` through the worksheet so you'd need to change your structure to something like this:

```
Public Function first(P As String) As String
    first = ext(P)(1)
End Function

Private Function ext(P As String) As Collection
    Dim serv As New Collection
    serv.Add P, "1"
    Set ext = serv
End Function
```

On the worksheet you'd just use the `first` function:

```
=first("Apple")
```